# DeclarationError: Identifier not found or not unique. function tokenURL(uint256_tokenId) public view override returns (string memory)

Tags: solidity, remix, dapps

```
function tokenURL(uint256_tokenId) public view override returns (string memory){
    bytes memory dataURI = abi.encodePacked(
        '{',
            '"name":', '"',tweets[_tokenId].name,'",' '"description":' , '"', tweets[_tokenId].description,'"', ',' ,
            '"attributes":', '[', '{', '"trait_type":', '"Upvotes",' , '"value":', Strings.toString(tweets[_tokenId].upvotes), '}',']','}'
    );

    return string (
        abi.encodePacked(
            "data:application/json;base64,",
            base64.encode(dataURI)
        )
    );
}
```

my code idk why is it showing this error i imported zeppelin library for ERC721 token but idk it is showing this error of declaration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you use the ERC721 implementation from Openzepellin, the function you want to override is `tokenURI` and not `tokenURL`.
The below should work :

```
function tokenURI(uint256 _tokenId) public view override returns (string memory){
//...
}
```

If you don't want to override openzepellin `tokenURI` and want to write your own function, you shouldn't use `override` keyword. Hence the below should also work:

```
function tokenURL(uint256 _tokenId) public view returns (string memory){
//...
}
```

Also there is a typo `uint256 _tokenId` with space and not `uint256_tokenId` in your code

Comment: Yep it worked. Thanks for the help 
it was a typo